# Implement Embeddable Custom Badges in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, embed

I want organically promoting in my application`(Laravel)` is to provide `badges`; snippets of content that people can embed on their own websites `(When a website url is stored in our database)`.

Something like `DMCA` embed code or `google partner badge` or etc.

But I do not think there is any solution. Please explain how to do this widget.

this is sample embede code from DMCA

```
<a href="//www.dmca.com/Protection/Status.aspx?ID=30b77" title="DMCA.com Protection Status" class="dmca-badge"> <img src ="https://images.dmca.com/Badges/dmca-badge-w100-5x1-08.png?ID=30b77" alt="DMCA.com Protection Status" /></a> <script src="https://images.dmca.com/Badges/DMCABadgeHelper.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: Do you have problem giving html code to clients or how to implement protection?

Comment: @MHIdea How to implement and build this program in Laravel. I have no solution I do not know how to start it

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a view and give it parameters like ID in badge example. e.g.

```php
return view('badge',['id'=>4569879])->render();
```

If you check the badge, there is script tag. it adds current page URL to href. On your laravel define a get route that receives ID and URL. That's it. Now you can give any service you like to that page.